# problem with connecting mongodb with with express NodeJs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

when i add **connectDB();** to the app.js, the app crashes and i tried to install the dotenv and it successfully installed and i made sure that i requested the dotenv before calling the function.

I am trying to set the test database for the testing purpose, but its not working.

I am trying to connect to mongodb using mongoose, but finding problem in connection error shows:

app.js code

```
     //requiring all modules
    
    const express = require('express');
    
    const dotenv = require('dotenv');
    
    dotenv.config();
    
    const morgan = require('morgan');
    
    const app = express();
    
    const path = require('path');
    
    const bodyparser = require('body-parser'); //adding body parts module
    
    //configuration
    
    app.enable('case sensitive routing');
    
    app.enable('etag');
    
    app.set('env', 'development');
    
    //connection of DataBase
    
    const connectDB = require('./server/database/connection');
    
    
    
    // For Port 
    dotenv.config({ path: 'config.env' });
    
    const PORT = process.env.PORT || 8080
    
    //log requests 
    app.use(morgan('tiny'));
    
    //mongodb connection 
    
    connectDB();

    .
    .
    // Server Port

app.listen(PORT, function() {

    console.log(`server is running on http://localhost:${PORT}`);
});
```

connection.js which its the file that has the connection :

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');



const connectDB = async() => {
    try {


        const con = await mongoose.connect(process.env.MONGO_URI, {

           
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useCreateIndex: true
        })

        console.log(`MongoDB connected : ${con.connection.host}`);

    } catch (err) {

        //if there is any problem 

        console.log(err);

        process.exit(1);

    }

}


module.exports = connectDB
```

config.env file:

```
    port = 3000

MONGO_URL=....
```

the problem in log :

```
    nodemon] restarting due to changes...
[nodemon] starting `node app.js`
server is running on http://localhost:3000
MongooseError: The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string.
    at NativeConnection.Connection.openUri (E:\.nodeJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\connection.js:684:11)
    at E:\.nodeJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:330:10
    at E:\.nodeJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:32:5
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at promiseOrCallback (E:\.nodeJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:31:10)
    at Mongoose._promiseOrCallback (E:\.nodeJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:1151:10)
    at Mongoose.connect (E:\.nodeJS\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:329:20)
    at connectDB (E:\.nodeJS\server\database\connection.js:18:36)
    at Object.<anonymous> (E:\.nodeJS\app.js:41:1)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1085:14)
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Comment: What is not clear with error message "The `uri` parameter to `openUri()` must be a string, got "undefined". Make sure the first parameter to `mongoose.connect()` or `mongoose.createConnection()` is a string."? Maybe print the connection string before you use it..

Answer (score 0):

path connection URI to `connectDB()` function like this

```
connectDB(process.env.MONGO_URI)
```

and read value in `connection.js`

```
const connectDB = async(uri) => {
    try {


        const con = await mongoose.connect(uri, {

           
            useNewUrlParser: true,
            useUnifiedTopology: true,
            useFindAndModify: false,
            useCreateIndex: true
        })

        console.log(`MongoDB connected : ${con.connection.host}`);

    } catch (err) {

        //if there is any problem 

        console.log(err);

        process.exit(1);

    }

}
```

Comment: added but no change

Comment: try this , my answer has been updated

Comment: unfortunately, the error still occurs. on the app,js file i passed this value to the connectDB function. and in the connection.js file, i added your code and on top of it i required mongoose and in the bottom of it, i exports connectDB. the error still occurs

Comment: could you get value in connection.js ?

Comment: What do u mean by that

Comment: in connectDB function add console.log(uri) and see what you get